# NullPointerException getting bean class name in @Produces method

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, logback, slf4j, java-ee-8

I have this `LoggerProducer` class that's injected in a `@Stateless` bean to generate log entries as explained [here](https://www.pavel.cool/jee-tips/Injecting-Logger/).

Problem is that when `CustomerBean` is invoked (without even calling `logger.info`), the `@Produces` method (that retrieves the bean class name) fails with `NullPointerException`. What is wrong with this code?

```
@Named
@Singleton
public class LoggerProducer {

    @Produces
    public Logger produceLogger(InjectionPoint injectionPoint) {
        return LoggerFactory.getLogger(
                   injectionPoint.getBean().getBeanClass()); // <- error here
    }   

}
```

The bean that injects the logger:

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;

@Stateless
@LocalBean
@Named
public class CustomerBean  {

    @Inject
    private Logger logger;

    ......
      logger.info("some message");
```

Comment: What is null: injectionPoint or getBean() ?

Comment: getBean() is null

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that `injectionPoint` is not null (in your producer method), you can try this:

```
@Produces 
Logger createLogger(InjectionPoint injectionPoint) { 
    return LoggerFactory.getLogger( injectionPoint.getMember().getDeclaringClass().getName() );
}
```